# MVVM Binding a property of object

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

Have the problem with binding, if I bind  string type Property everything work fine, but if  I trying to bind in View the object property of Property xaml not upload.

No any Errors or warnings.

Upadated Model

Model:

```
     public class Part : BindableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public string _BrandImage;
    public string BrandImage
    {
        get { return _BrandImage; }
        set
        {
            _BrandImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Article { get; set; }
    public string Mfg { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }   


        };

            return result;
        }

    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PartDetailViewModel :  BindableBase
    {
        private Part part;
        public Part Part
        {
            get { return part; }
            set { SetProperty(ref part, value); }
        }   

        public PartDetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) 
        {
            Part = part.GetPartById();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: The line `Part = part.GetPartById();` can't be correct - part will be null at this moment. And: did you forget the curly braces in `Source="Binding Part.BrandImage"`?

Comment: Did you solve this issue or you want me to answer this?

Comment: not solved  yet (

Comment: curly braces was  loosed  but it is not main problem

Comment: @KlausGütter 
why null ?

Comment: Because it is not set to any other value before. But maybe you just mis-typed. As written now, it will not even compile, because Part has no method GetPartById().

Comment: Maybe your data do not set in `Part` successfully.You can Check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inherit 'BindableObject' and notify the view about the property changed inside the setter 'set {}' for the properties that you are binding in the view. I have modified your code below for Name property, you can change based on your requirements for other fields.

```
public class Part : BindableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string BrandImage { get; set; }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Article { get; set; }
    public string Mfg { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: change two property's, which usein View,  for test, did't help

Comment: I didn't get. Can you explain? Can you post your code here?

Comment: Updated Model in the start topic

Comment: try sending name as well, like OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BrandImage));

Comment: norhig change
I think main problem here     
 Part = part.GetPartById();

Comment: Are you fetching Part data from this line 'private Part part;' becoz, this line is referring that 'part.GetPartById();'. I htink, you have missed something here, should be fetching from list instead of part.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this property from model and thats help

```
 public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
```